# Select Days from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
╔════════════╦═══════╗
║ DATE       ║ VALUE ║
╠════════════╬═══════╣
║ 2011-01-07 ║ 1     ║
╠════════════╬═══════╣
║ 2011-01-08 ║ 2     ║
╠════════════╬═══════╣
║ 2011-01-09 ║ 1     ║
╠════════════╬═══════╣
║ 2011-01-10 ║ 1     ║
╠════════════╬═══════╣
║ 2011-01-20 ║ 1     ║
╠════════════╬═══════╣
║ 2011-01-20 ║ 1     ║
╚════════════╩═══════╝
```

What I want do do now is to select three days starting from 2011-01-20. Selecting via `df.loc['2011-01-20' - pd.Timedelta(3, unit='d'):'2011-01-20']` results in the following date frame:

```
╔════════════╦═══════╗
║ DATE       ║ VALUE ║
╠════════════╬═══════╣
║ 2011-01-20 ║ 1     ║
╠════════════╬═══════╣
║ 2011-01-20 ║ 1     ║
╚════════════╩═══════╝
```

What I want to accomplish is the following data frame:

```
╔════════════╦═══════╗
║ DATE       ║ VALUE ║
╠════════════╬═══════╣
║ 2011-01-09 ║ 1     ║
╠════════════╬═══════╣
║ 2011-01-10 ║ 1     ║
╠════════════╬═══════╣
║ 2011-01-20 ║ 1     ║
╠════════════╬═══════╣
║ 2011-01-20 ║ 1     ║
╚════════════╩═══════╝
```

What I don't want to do is to `groupby` or resample the data frame or anything like that because I need to preserve the structure for the following processing. Does anybody know how I can solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve... Do you want to select all dates between `2011-01-17` and `2011-01-20` - in this case i don't understand your desired data set...

Comment: No, I don't want to resample the data frame. I want to get i.e. three different dates prior (but including) ```2011-01-20``` and keep all dates which appear more than once resulting in a data frame as shown in the last table above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a consecutive id column so that each date has a unique id which increases with the date and then subset based on the id column:

```
import pandas as pd
# sort the `DATE` column and create an id for each date
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE).sort_values()
df['DateId'] = df.groupby('DATE').grouper.group_info[0]

# find out the id for the target date
MaxId = df.DateId[df.DATE == '2011-01-20'].drop_duplicates().values

# subset based on the id column and the MaxId
df.loc[df.DateId.isin(range(MaxId - 2, MaxId + 1)),['DATE', 'VALUE']]

#         DATE  VALUE
# 2 2011-01-09      1
# 3 2011-01-10      1
# 4 2011-01-20      1
# 5 2011-01-20      1
```

Comment: What a smart idea. It worked out great for my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I like your "ranking" idea! I think we could also use rank() method - `df.assign(date_rank=df.DATE.rank(method='min').astype(int))`

Comment: @MaxU `rank()` method is a more concise way for this problem. Didn't know this method before. Definitely a plus to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using [pandas.ix](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html)
 Hint: `df.ix(start, stop)`

```
df['Date'] =pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).sort_values()
df.ix[df[df.Date =='2011-01-20'].index[0]-2: max(df[df.Date =='2011-01-20'].index)] 

       Date   Value
2 2011-01-09      1
3 2011-01-10      1
4 2011-01-20      1
5 2011-01-20      1
6 2011-01-20      1
```